# Is there a way to make a jnlp file use a 64-bit JRE?

Tags: java, windows-7, java-web-start

I have two versions of a .jnlp to launch an app, one with the `java-vm-args="-Xmx4g"` jvm option to be run on machines with more memory, and one with the `java-vm-args="-Xmx1g"` to be run on machines with less memory.
I would like the .jnlp with the `-Xmx4g` option to run on a 64 bit JRE if it is available, however, .jnlp files are always launched with Java(TM) Web Start Launcher, which by default always uses the 32 bit JRE if both the 32bit and 64bit versions of the same JRE release (I'm have both the 32 and 64 bit versions of Java 8 v121 installed).

Is there a way to make `Java(TM) Web Start Launcher` use the 64 bit JRE instead of the default 32 bit JRE for this particular .jnlp?  The users using this app in the field must also have a 32 bit JRE installed to run older legacy apps, so uninstalling the 32 bit JRE is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way, but one workaround is to right click the jnlp and choose the 64bit java executable to launch the jnlp file.

Comment: Could you add some details on this?

Comment: You can run the command   <java-home/bin>javaws.exe <url or path of jnlp>        Or right click the jnlp file -> openwith -> browse to 64bit java folder -> select javaws.exe

Comment: Thanks, i tried this, but it doesn't work, at least not on Win7.  When I right click on the .jnlp file and try to choose the javaws.exe as the default program to run it with, it does not show up under "Recommended Programs" as one of the executables I can choose to run this file.  I think this is because, as per FileInfo [link](https://fileinfo.com/extension/jnlp), the only executables that can run .jnlp files are Oracle Java Web Start, or a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct it in the jnlp file:

```
<resources arch="amd64">
```

From the documentation:

> arch
>
> Specifies the architecture for which this information element should
>   be considered

Comment: In my experience, that section doesn't direct which JVM should be used -- instead, it tells Java that "IF I am running on a amd64 JVM, apply/use these enclosed resources." Indeed the JNLP file can include multiple "resources" sections, each with a different "arch" attribute value. This is useful if your Java application uses native libraries, and your application bundles all of these native libraries. These sections tell Java which native libraries to load.